# form Submit AJAX + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

On Sunday, I made a working script to send form data into my database and email with Mandrill.

Since Wednesday, my script doesn't work anymore. I'm trying to find the error but nothing fixed it.

I think I have an error in my PHP script but I don't know where and what.
Console log of my AJAX returns correct data but PHP doesn't do anything. It doesn't receive data.

There is my **HTML**

```
<form method="POST" id="formContact" action"#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Prénom" name="name" id="formName">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="formEmail">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Sujet" name="subject" id="formSubject">
                <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ton message" name="message" id="formMessage"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" id="formSubmit">Envoyer</button>
            </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#formContact').submit(function(event) {
    var formData = {
        'name' : $('#formName').val(),
        'email' : $("#formEmail").val(),
        'subject' : $("#formSubject").val(),
        'message' : $("#formMessage").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "commons/test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(formData);
        console.log(data);

        if( ! data.success){
            alert('Error');
        }else{
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include('../adm/dbconnect.php'); <- this work well
    $data = array();
    if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['message']))
    {
        // var_dump($_POST['name']);
        // var_dump($_POST['email']);
        // var_dump($_POST['subject']);
        // var_dump($_POST['message']);

        $to = 'contact@sheguey.land';
        $content = ''.$_POST['message'].'';
        $subject = 'Nouveau message de '.$_POST['email'].' - Sheguey Land';
        $from = ''.$_POST['email'].'';

        $uri = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json';
        $api_key = 'my mandrill api key';
        $content_text = strip_tags($content);

        $postString = '{
            "key": "' . $api_key . '",
            "message": {
            "html": "' . $content . '",
            "text": "' . $content_text . '",
            "subject": "' . $subject . '",
            "from_email": "' . $from . '",
            "from_name": "' . $from . '",
            "to": [
            {
                "email": "' . $to . '",
                "name": "' . $to . '"
            }
            ],
            "track_opens": true,
            "track_clicks": true,
            "auto_text": true,
            "url_strip_qs": true,
            "preserve_recipients": true
            },
            "async": false
        }';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);



        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO contactform (name, email, subject, message) VALUES( :name,  :email,  :subject,  :message)');
        $req->execute(array(
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
                'message' => $_POST['message']
            ));
        $data['success'] = true;

    }else{
        $data['success'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

After two days of research (changing PHP script, AJAX script, etc), I don't understand why this don't work anymore.

Comment: Yes i have, 0 errors are detected.

Comment: How far does the script go? No further than the include, or does it stop on a certain line? Try figuring out with `var_dump()`/`echo`s.

Comment: it goes to the "if" line, say all the $_POST[''] are probably empty and echo the "$data = false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the problem and fixed it.

A .htaccess file was in the same folder as the PHP file, i don't know why it was there. The script work.

Anyway thanks for you help ;)

Answer (score 0):

you might need quotes in formData '"' + $('#formName').val() + '"'

Answer (score 0):

What is the reasoning for the double single quotes?

```
$content = ''.$_POST['message'].'';
$subject = 'Nouveau message de '.$_POST['email'].' - Sheguey Land';
$from = ''.$_POST['email'].'';
```

I would just have done it as follows:

```
$content = (string)$_POST['message'];
$subject = "Nouveau message de ".$_POST['email']." - Sheguey Land";
$from    = (string)$_POST['email'];
```

Does it var_dump the $_POST values after the if statement if you uncomment one?

```
var_dump($_POST); //as a whole
```

You may want to set error_reporting(E_ALL); to error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT); which sometimes provides you with more information.